# How to fix 'Reference to type 'IAsyncEnumerable<>' claims it is defined in 'System.Interactive.Async', but it could not be found'?

Tags: c#, discord.net

Until yesterday it was working and I didn't even touch the code but this error popped up and since that it just says this:

> Reference to type 'IAsyncEnumerable<>' claims it is defined in
>   'System.Interactive.Async', but it could not be found.

I did a discord bot and I want to delete messages with it

```
        [Command("clear")]
        public async Task Clear(string StringNum = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Context.Guild.CurrentUser.GuildPermissions.ManageMessages)
                {
                    await ReplyAsync("Sorry, I don't have permission for this!");
                }
                else
                {
                    var user = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
                    if (user.GuildPermissions.ManageMessages)
                    {
                        int IntNum = 1;
                        bool intparse = int.TryParse(StringNum, out int n);
                        if (intparse)
                        {
                            IntNum = int.Parse(StringNum);
                        }

                        var messages = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(IntNum + 1).Flatten();
                        await (Context.Channel as SocketTextChannel).DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await ReplyAsync("You don't have permission for this command!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException());
            }
        }
```

The error is at the line where I try to get the messages

Comment: That's not a code thing, it's a reference thing. You are sure you have set a reference to System.Interactive.Async ?
Very likely, if it already worked.
Sometimes, if you change the platform target (x86/x64) or the version of .NET Framework, the referenced DLL can become incompatible. From System Dlls it most often will find the correct path, but it depends on how set the reference. If by picking a file from the file system, this is hard coded and not moving.
Just an idea to check.

Comment: There was a package update and apparently that just broke my code

Comment: I removed the explicit reference to System.Interactive.Async 4.0.0 from csproj and the error has gone.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this. I had to install System.Interactive.Async 3.1.1 rather than 4.0.0. So I assume it is no longer in 4.0.0.